# Extremely nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I struggling with an extremely nested dictionary. I need to get "main_id" of dictionary only if there is "name": "bingo" in it.

```
example_dict = [{'main_id': 10000,
             'example_field': {'group': {'count': 3, 'results': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'AAA'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'BBB'},
                                                                 {'id': 3, 'name': 'CCC'}]}}},
            {'main_id': 20000,
             'example_field': {
                 'group': {'count': 3, 'results': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'AAA'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'BBB'},
                                                   {'id': 3, 'name': 'bingo'}]}}}
            ]
```

I have solution but in my opinion is quite ugly.

```
for elem in example_dict:
result = ([elem for elem in elem['example_field']['group']['results'] if elem.get('name') == 'bingo'])
if result:
    main_id = elem['main_id']
    print(main_id)
```

I am wonder if:

- There is some better and clean way to achieve it (always is ;))?
- How to make it reusable?
- Is it possible to close it in just one list comprehension?

Comment: `[x['main_id'] for x in example_dict if any([v['name']=='bingo' for v in x['example_field']['group']['results']])]`

Comment: @Chris thank you a lot. Your answer helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

**#One liner - list comprehension**

```py
result = [ print(element['main_id']) for element in example_dict if element['example_field']['group']['results'][2]['name']== 'bingo']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your dicts has regular structure - in such case you can use some library for parsing it into class, [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) could be a good choice:

```
from typing import List
from pydantic.main import BaseModel


class Field(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


class Main(BaseModel):
    fields: List[Field]


d = {"fields": [{"id": 1, "name": "a"}, {"id": 2, "name": "b"}]}

c = Main(**d)
print(c)
```

That's just an example but you can have more nested classes.
With it you can just write `[f for f in c.fields if f.name == "bingo"]`

Answer (score 0):

**#Reusability**

```py
def check_bingo(example_dict):
    
    #list comprehension
    result = [element['main_id'] for element in example_dict if element['example_field']['group']['results'][2]['name']== 'bingo']
    
    return result[0] #gets the first element

check_bingo(example_dict) #passing dict to function
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).